# image only displayed when while loop is over

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some code that works fine

```
while [whatever]:
   image = Image.open(..)
   photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
   label = Label(image = photo)
   label.image = photo
   label.pack()
   [...]
```

However, the image is only displayed after the `while` loop is done. Why is that?

I wouldn't mind everything stopping until the image is shown.

Comment: Is this part of an event handler? Can the UI be updated before the event handler completes? I don't know python/tkinter, but in some GUI systems you would have to let the event handler complete, and have the rest of the work of the while loop (after the label is set up) done on another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple:

`root.update()` does the trick!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @GingerHead I didn't post a link?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the image loader for the library you are using is asynchronous and so the image is not shown until the pixel data is ready, and your while loop has already quit.

If you want to block (stop execution) until the image has been loaded, check for a callback or property of the object that lets the main thread pause until it's done. For example `while !image.ready:` then inside that scope `Sleep()`.

Maybe this will help, probably not though as I have limited knowledge of Python and much less of its **tkinter** module.